Short story with floating hat-shaped animals that can be taken over by a frog-like animal
Decades ago, I read a short story in an anthology, where there are floating animals shaped like broad-brimmed hats, which move slowly, almost plant-like; they have paddles underneath.  People can direct their movement by blasting heat at the side they want the animal to move away from, and they use them as transport.
Someone riding on one of these finds it goes out of his control, and he swims underneath and finds that a frog-like animal (perhaps roughly human-sized) has swum up into the centre of the "hat" from underneath and made neural connections to it and taken it over.
I think the human then kills the animal that is controlling the floating one.

Grandpa! It's a duplicate of Short story about exobiology during human exploration of an alien planet. The answer to that question includes: They looked somewhat like exceptionally broad-brimmed, well-worn sugar-loaf hats floating out there, green and leathery. Or like lily pads twenty-five feet across, with the upper section of a big, grey-green pineapple growing from the centre of each. so it's obviously the same as your story.

Yes, that's the one, thanks!

Nicely done @JohnRennie :)
